# Custom content entity: can't hide translation details in edit form

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n

I've created a multi-lingual custom content entity using Drupal Console. The basic stuff with editing/viewing works fine, also multi-lingual. But for some reason, I can't hide the "Translation" details form element (the one with the translation meta data) in the entity's edit form.

Screenshot of form display settings:
[image: Settings in form display]

Screenshot of edit form:
[image: Translation details still visible in edit form]

In the config export `core.entity_form_display.chunk.weather_daswetter.default.yml` the translation also is listed correctly in the `hidden` section:

```
id: chunk.weather_daswetter.default
targetEntityType: chunk
bundle: weather_daswetter
mode: default
third_party_settings:
  stuff_from_field_group_module_here: nothing_with_translation
content:
  all_visible_fields_listed_correctly
hidden:
  changed: true
  created: true
  langcode: true
  translation: true
  uid: true
```

Into the blue I've tried relisting the fields from core's ContentTranslationHandler in my own `src/Entity/Chunk.php->baseFieldDefinitions()` and explicitly set them configurable, but this did not help either:

```
/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "chunk",
 *    ...
 *   translatable = TRUE,
 *   ...
 * )
 */
class Chunk extends ContentEntityBase implements ChunkInterface {
  use EntityOwnerTrait;
  use EntityChangedTrait;
  use EntityPublishedTrait;

  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
    $fields += static::ownerBaseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
    $fields += static::publishedBaseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

    // tried adding this, did not help
    if ($fields['content_translation_status']) {
      $fields['content_translation_status']->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
    }

    if ($fields['content_translation_outdated']) {
      $fields['content_translation_outdated']->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
    }

    if ($fields['content_translation_uid']) {
      $fields['content_translation_uid']->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
    }

    if ($fields['content_translation_created']) {
      $fields['content_translation_created']->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
    }
  }
}
```

Why doesn't the form display mode control for "Translation" work?

I really want to keep this visible and configurable in the UI and therefore want to avoid using `hook_form_alter`.

UPDATE:
I've tried using hook_form_alter, but this doesn't work either:

```
function wt_chunks_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#entity_type'] == 'chunk') {
    /** @var $formMode \Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityFormDisplay */
    $formMode = $form_state->getStorage()['form_display'];
    $hiddenFields = $formMode->get('hidden');
    if (in_array('translation', $hiddenFields)) {
      //code goes into here, but the key 'content_translation' 
      //does not exist in the $form array
      $form['content_translation']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `translation` field that you try to disable is not the one containing the metadata.

The translation metadata is generated in `Drupal\content_translation\ContentTranslationHandler` and is automatically applied if following access check is true:

```
'#access' => $this->getTranslationAccess($entity, $new_translation ? 'create' : 'update')->isAllowed(),
```

To solve this problem you can add a checkbox to your entity settings form that allows you to disable the translation.

You will also need to create a custom `TranslationHandler` for you entity.

In the annotations of your entity add this under `handlers`:

```
"translation" = "Drupal\MY_MODULE\MyEntityTranslationHandler",
```

Your custom translation handler can then be something like this:

```
namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class MyEntityTranslationHandler extends ContentTranslationHandler {

  public function entityFormAlter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, EntityInterface $entity) {
    $form = parent::entityFormAlter($form, $form_state, $entity);
    if (// Some condition...) {
      $form['content_translation']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }

}
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: OK, got this. But what is the point of the "Translation" field in the form display? Instead of creating a new, quite dislocated setting somewhere else, I'd rather use the form display config for the existing Translation field in the if-clause of  hook_form_alter. Is this a safe approach or has the existing Translation field some other unknown purpose?

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. When I use `hook_form_alter(&$form)` in my custom module, the key `content_translation` does not yet exist in the `$form` array. Somehow the translation handler seems to run after my hook?

Comment: @Hudri I have updated my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, this works. A stub translation handler was already created and set by Drupal console's boilerplate code. Just needed to move my code from `.module` to the handler class.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here is the working code I acutally use to make the hiding via form display mode functional:

(My custom entity's name is `chunk`)

file `src/Entity/Chunk.php`

```
namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE\Entity;

use ...

/**
 * Defines the Chunk entity.
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "chunk",
 *   label = @Translation("Chunk"),
 *   ...
 *   handlers = {
 *     ...
 *     "translation" = "Drupal\MY_MODULE\ChunkTranslationHandler",
 *     ...
 *   },
 *   translatable = TRUE,
 *   ...
 * )
 */
class Chunk extends ContentEntityBase implements ChunkInterface {
  ...
  // no special code required here, just notice the translation handler annotation above
  ...
```

file `src/ChunkTranslationHandler.php`

```
namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE;

use Drupal\content_translation\ContentTranslationHandler;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Defines the translation handler for chunk.
 */
class ChunkTranslationHandler extends ContentTranslationHandler {

  public function entityFormAlter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, EntityInterface $entity) {
    parent::entityFormAlter($form, $form_state, $entity);
    /** @var $formMode \Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityFormDisplay */
    $formMode = $form_state->getStorage()['form_display'];
    $hiddenFields = $formMode->get('hidden');
    if (in_array('translation', $hiddenFields) && array_key_exists('content_translation', $form)) {
      $form['content_translation']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the same @JDrupal's solution above, but actually uses the form display config of the `Translation` field (i.e. if you move it to the disabled section in the UI, all translation meta data fields are hidden).

If you use Drupal console's `drupal generate:entity:content` you just need to write the custom `entityFormAlter()` function.