# What is the purpose of Translation field in form display mode?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

When editing the form display mode of a translatable content entity, there is a field called `Translation` in the UI. I thought this field would manage the weight/visibility of translation meta data fields (like `content_translation_uid` or `content_translation_outdated`) in the entity's edit form.

But moving that field around doesn't have any effect, it neither reorders the position, nore does it hide the Translation `<details>` element when I move it into the disabled section.

So, what is the real purpose of the field `Translation` in `/admin/structure/ENTITY/manage/BUNDLE/form-display` ?

(This is a follow-up of my question  [Custom content entity: can't hide translation details in edit form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/289367/custom-content-entity-cant-hide-translation-details-in-edit-form))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extra field (Drupal term for a pseudo field not stored in the database you can move around in UI), which is added when *Content Translation* is enabled:  [content_translation_entity_extra_field_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_translation%21content_translation.module/function/content_translation_entity_extra_field_info/8.8.x)

See this issue:

> **content_translation_entity_extra_field_info is obsolete**
>
> **Problem/Motivation**
>
> content_translation_entity_extra_field_info is adding the extra field
>   "Translation" but it is not used by content_translation in the form
>   alter hooks and it only confuses when we are on the form display
>   configuring the fields and reordering it doesn't change anything on
>   the edit page.
>
> **Proposed resolution**
>
> Remove content_translation_entity_extra_field_info
>   and remove the "translation" component from all saved form display
>   configs.

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2856551